# Pass a `lambda` function in `.yml` file

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I need to pass all my variables through an `.yml` file. Although, there is no problem passing a `str` variables, I can't figure out how can I pass something more sophisticated, such as `python`s' `lambda` function.

The following code demonstrates my problem:

The `.yml` file:

```
{
    csv_2_df: {
        time_stamp_params: {
         column_name: '@timestamp',
         extraction_lambda: lambda s: s[1:11] + ' ' + s[12:-2],
         format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
        }
    }
}
```

so, in the example above, if I try to parse it with the

```
with open(YAML_PATH, 'r') as f:
    configs = yaml.full_load(f)
```

it throws an exception:

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a flow mapping
  in "configs.yml", line 14, column 28
expected ',' or '}', but got ':'
  in "configs.yml", line 16, column 37
```

So, how can I pass a `python`s' `lambda` function in a `.yml` file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you could store the lambda expression as a string in the yml and use eval to go from string to function.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Why didn't you post it as an answer so I could credit you?

Comment: Glad I could help. Keep in mind that `eval` is pretty much unsafe from a security point of view.